# Sorting arrays by date

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've got a question. I'm building an array by getting data from mysql and merging three query results in one array.

I put data to array like this:

```
while ($a = mysql_fetch_object($activities)) {
            $a->type = 1;
            $array1[] = $a;
        }
        while ($k = mysql_fetch_object($fuups)) {
        $k->type = 2;
            $array1[] = $k;
        }
        while ($x = mysql_fetch_object($refuups)) {
            $x->type = 3;
            $array1[] = $x;
        }

        return (object)$array1;
```

This returns something like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [added] => 2012-01-17 07:33:53
            [type] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [added] => 2012-01-13 06:36:22
            [type] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [added_type_2] => 2012-01-09 04:01:12
            [type] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [added_type_2] => 2012-02-08 02:08:32
            [type] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [added_type_2] => 2012-01-25 00:09:08
            [type] => 2
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [added_type_3] => 2012-01-23 00:09:08
            [type] => 3
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [added_type_3] => 2012-01-22 00:09:08
            [type] => 3
        )

)
```

I tried things like asort, ksort, sort but no luck. also getting the dates with "order by added desc" thank you

Comment: just a thought can you call those three query and create union and get one result.. easy to sort in sql..?

Comment: I also tried that but i can't figure out how will php know what is the type of content that query getting

Comment: Not so sure about this kind of sorting, but can you sort it using query and fetch it from database in desirable order?

Comment: Have you tried selecting "TO_UNIXTIME([date field]) AS `timestamp`" and storing the array as "$array[$a->timestamp]"?  Then you have a numeric keyed array that is easy to sort and will take less PHP to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use usort() if you change fetch object to fetch assoc:

```
function my_date_sort($a,$b) {
   if(isset($a[0]) && isset($b[0])) {
       $a = strtotime($a[0]); // optionally convert to time
       $b = strtotime($b[0]);
       if($a == $b) return 0; 
       else return ($a > $b) ? 1 : -1;
   } else { // no valid subs, change this to put empty ones on top or bottom
       return 1; // put at bottom, -1 would put at top. 
}


usort($results, 'my_date_sort');
```

Good luck...

Comment: +1 FYI, straight string comparisons would work in his particular case, forgoing the need for strtotime: `if ('2012-01-17 07:33:53' > '2012-01-13 06:36:22')` would actually work fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is sort a multidimensional array, you can find plenty on Google about this. A nice elegant solution would be something like:

```
// Sort the multidimensional array
usort($results, "custom_sort");

// Define the custom sort function
function custom_sort($a,$b) {
     return $a['some_sub_var']>$b['some_sub_var'];
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

For those in the comments doubting whether this code would work, please feel free to try it out (I even added in a date that's a duplicate for testing purposes):

```
function custom_sort($a,$b) {
        return $a['added']>$b['added'];
}

$arrayToSort = array(
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-17 07:33:53",
                        "type" => "1"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-13 06:36:22",
                        "type" => "1"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-09 04:01:12",
                        "type" => "2"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-02-08 02:08:32",
                        "type" => "2"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-25 00:09:08",
                        "type" => "2"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-13 06:36:22",
                        "type" => "1"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-13 06:36:22",
                        "type" => "1"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-23 00:09:08",
                        "type" => "3"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "added" => "2012-01-22 00:09:08",
                        "type" => "3"
                    )
                );
usort($arrayToSort, "custom_sort");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrayToSort);
echo '</pre>';
```

A good place to test quickly would be to go to http://writecodeonline.com/php/.

Comment: @Garry Welding: If `$a` is less than `$b`, your code will return `0` (actually `null`) rather than `-1`. `0` is supposed to be returned if they are equal. You need to read the documentation.

Comment: I would encourage the two commenters above to actually try the code.

Comment: @Garry Welding: I have tried it and you are correct. It sorts it the same regardless if `-1` is returned or not. Curious, I went to the source code and it turns out that Zend does not care what number is returned, only if it is greater than zero or not: From `zend_qsort.c`: `compare(begin, seg1 TSRMLS_CC) > 0`. So, despite the documentation (and unless their quick sort implementation is changed in the near future, which is highly doubtful), it appears that return values of `-1` or `0` **are treated exactly the same.** + 1

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) when selecting and not trying to sort arrays on your own. Anyway if you have to may use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) like this:

```
function cmp( $a, $b){
  if( !($a instanceOf stdClass) && !($b instanceOf stdClass)){
    return 0;
  }

  // Check object
  if(  !($a instanceOf stdClass)){
    return -1;
  }
  if(  !($b instanceOf stdClass)){
    return 1;
  }

  $aVal = NULL;
  if( isset( $a->added)){
    $aVal = $a->added;
  } elseif( isset( $a->added_type_2)){
    $aVal = $a->added_type_2;
  } ...

  // The same for b
  if( ($aVal == NULL) && ($bVal == NULL)){
    return 0;
  }

  if( $aVal == NULL){
    return -1;
  }

  if( $bVal == NULL){
    return 1;
  }

  if( $aVal == $bVal){
    return 0;
  }

  return ($aVal > $bVal) ? 1 : -1;

}

usort( $array, 'cmp');
```

As you may see the condition how to compare object may get complex when making sure they have correct types and correct values. When selecting mysql columns you should use at least `SELECT added_type_2 AS added` to have column names more compact and conditions simpler.