# How to sort date array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I am new to php, I have php date array

```
[0] => 11-01-2012
[1] => 01-01-2014
[2] => 01-01-2015
[3] => 09-02-2013
[4] => 01-01-2013
```

I want to sort it like :

```
[0] => 11-01-2012
[1] => 01-01-2013
[2] => 09-02-2013
[3] => 01-01-2014
[4] => 01-01-2015
```

I use `asort` but not working.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to sort strings instead of dates. You should convert your data to real dates (DateTime objects or timestamps); then you can manipulate them very easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401714/php-order-array-by-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting arrays by date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203079/sorting-arrays-by-date)

Comment: Despite my change to the title, the [mcve] isn't crystal clear about whether the strings are `d-m-Y` or `m-d-Y`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If the date is in "Mysql" format (`Y-m-d` or `Y-m-d H:i:s`), then you can sort your array right away, no special action needed:

```
$arr = ["2019-11-11", "2019-10-10","2019-11-11", "2019-09-08","2019-05-11"];
sort($arr);
```

If the date is localized or formatted anyhow (that you should avoid, formatting the date only before output) you have to use a custom sorting function, such as [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), that will convert the dates into sortable format before comparison.

The simplest way to convert a date into sortable format is to convert it into uninx timestamp using [`strtotime()`](https://php.net/strtotime) function:

```
$arr = ['11/01/2012', '03/16/2022', '12/26/2021', '01/01/2014', '09/02/2013'];
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
});
print_r($arr);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/JVYpr)

However, there could be pitfalls, because in different countries the same date format could mean a different date. Which is exactly the case with your example format, for which the above function will return wrong results if dates are `['03-16-2022', '12-26-2021', '06-06-2022']`. Therefore it's better to define the date format explicitly, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php#72695509)

Comment: what date format is this assuming? `['03-16-2022', '12-26-2021', '06-06-2022']` will not have correct output.

Answer (score 3):

The example dates data provided aren't clear what format they are. To be sure, you should use `DateTime::createFromFormat` and then specify the format explicitly:

```
$dates = ['11-01-2012', '03-16-2022', '12-26-2021', '01-01-2014', '01-01-2015', '09-02-2013', '01-01-2013'];

function sort_date($a, $b) {
    return \DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $a) <=> \DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $b);
}

usort($dates, "sort_date");
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63482679/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/39769867/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/59151489/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/23130621/2943403

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<?php 

$array = array('11-01-2012','01-01-2011','09-02-2013','01-01-2014','01-01-2015');

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a));
    $b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($b));

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($array, "cmp");

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "[$key]=> $value <br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: _Try this_ (code-only) answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and future researchers.   Please add an explanation of how your solution works and why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

out of the box use time function to generate ts and sort

```
<?php
  $out = array();
  // $your_array is the example obove
  foreach($your_array as $time) {
  $out[strtotime($time)] = $time;
  }
  // now $out has ts-keys and you can handle it

  ...
 ?>
```

[ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 
$array = [ '11-01-2012', '01-01-2014', '01-01-2015', '09-02-2013', '01-01-2013' ];
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
usort($array, "sortFunction");
var_dump( $array );
?>
```

Will sort the dates into the order you want.

Comment: Try this (code-only) answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and future researchers. Please add an explanation of how your solution works and why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by applying this line.

```
sort($imdarrayGG['newDate']);
```

Output before adding the value

```
[Mon Jul  6 10:33:23 2020] Array
(
    [coursedate] => 2020-07-17
    [newDate] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-07-30
            [1] => 2020-07-07
            [2] => 2020-07-08
            [3] => 2020-07-17
        )

)
```

After I put the line, the output will become like this.

```
[Mon Jul  6 10:35:42 2020] Array
(
    [coursedate] => 2020-07-17
    [newDate] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-07-07
            [1] => 2020-07-08
            [2] => 2020-07-17
            [3] => 2020-07-30
        )

)
```

The date already sorted which is the latest date will be at the up.

This is where we have object and then we want to sort all of them

Example:-

```
[status_custom] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => LDL - B2
                [date] => 23/10/2014
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => LDL - D
                [date] => 18/04/2015
            )
   )
```

First we have to convert. [Refer to this link to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435664/9346054)
And then we sort them. [Refer to this link to sort object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31729669/9346054)

Here we go:-

```
    //At here we want to sort according to latest date. But this one involve with the object also.
    usort($array_custom_object, function ($a, $b) {
        $date1 = $a->date;
        $date2 = $b->date;

        //Since the income date is formatted like this d/m/Y , we have to change it
        $date1 = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $date1), 'Y-m-d');
        $date2 = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $date2), 'Y-m-d');

        if ($date1 > $date2) {
            return -1;
        }
        if ($date1 == $date2) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ($date1 < $date2) {
            return 1;
        }
    });
    $dataFinal->status_custom = $array_custom_object; //Result
```

Answer (score -1):

use DateTime for sorting date :

```
$a = array(
    new DateTime('2016-01-02'),
    new DateTime('2016-05-01'),
    new DateTime('2015-01-01'),
    new DateTime('2016-01-01')
);
asort($a);
var_dump($a);
```

The output would be :

```
array(4) {
  [2]=>
  object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(10) "US/Pacific"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(10) "US/Pacific"
  }
  [0]=>
  object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2016-01-02 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(10) "US/Pacific"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2016-05-01 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(10) "US/Pacific"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer here is close if you have a list of DateTime or Carbon date objects.
However I believe you have negative down votes because you suggested using asort() instead of sort(), If users use asort() then numerical index references will not reflect the actual sorted list that is dumped.

Answer (score -1):

You definitely can sort array to timestamps with the given code below, but I would like to drag your attention to the format of time I have used to store.. There are different benefits of storing time in such format. Read more about this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59912185/7997043

```
function compareByTimeStamp($a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($b) - strtotime($a);
}
$arr = array("2020-02-11 00:00:00", "2020-02-13 00:00:00", "2020-02-08 00:00:00"); 
usort($arr, "compareByTimeStamp"); 
echo json_encode($arr);
```