# Sort in ASC order

Tags: php

```
9th May 2018    
9th May 2018
9th June 2018
9th August 2018     
8th May 2018
7th June 2018
7th June 2018
```

How to sort these dates in ascending order and these dates are in a associative array.

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of what you've tried so far ? From what you posted, it looks like you didn't try anything yet and just expect us to give you the answer. I would redirect you to the [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) then.

Comment: by array, it seems that it is a PHP only question

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Your edit has made your question clearer. Convert them to timestamps and use array sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort date array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) you can define any custom sort order, in this case converting the strings into times and comparing them:

```
$array = array("1" => "9th May 2018",
    "2" => "9th May 2018",
    "3" => "9th June 2018",
    "4" => "9th August 2018",
    "5" => "8th May 2018",
    "6" => "7th June 2018",
    "7" => "7th June 2018",
);

usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) > strtotime($b);
});

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: downvote with no reason? I've tested that it works... please comment if something is wrong