# How to sort array by first value if array is multidimensional?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The following creates a multidimensional array, where a date and id are pair objects:

```
if( $queryPosts->have_posts() ):
    $dateOrdered = [];
    while ( $queryPosts->have_posts() ) : $queryPosts->the_post();
        $id = $post->ID;
        $date = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-80');
        array_push($postOrdered, $id);
        $dateOrdered[] = array("date"=>$date, "id"=>$id);
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Then I need to run something like the following to sort by dates in order to then have a list of ordered by dates post ids too

```
function custom_sort_dt($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
usort($dateOrdered, "custom_sort_dt");
print_r($dateOrdered);
```

This is the print_r and dates are not ordered and so are not the ids

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 7-12-2018 [id] => 127902 ) [1] => Array ( [date] => 19-12-2018 [id] => 127982 ) [2] => Array ( [date] => 6-12-2018 [id] => 127987 ) [3] => Array ( [date] => 13-12-2018 [id] => 127899 ) [4] => Array ( [date] => 24-11-2000 [id] => 127891 ) [5] => Array ( [date] => 13-11-2018 [id] => 127867 ) [6] => Array ( [date] => 25-11-2018 [id] => 127869 ) [7] => Array ( [date] => 5-12-2018 [id] => 127990 ) [8] => Array ( [date] => 5-12-2018 [id] => 127992 ) [9] => Array ( [date] => 18-12-2018 [id] => 128009 ) [10] => Array ( [date] => 26-12-2018 [id] => 128011 ) [11] => Array ( [date] => 21-12-2018 [id] => 128015 ) [12] => Array ( [date] => 27-12-2018 [id] => 128005 ) [13] => Array ( [date] => 12-11-2018 [id] => 127999 ) [14] => Array ( [date] => 7-12-2018 [id] => 127994 ) [15] => Array ( [date] => 21-12-2018 [id] => 127996 ) [16] => Array ( [date] => 2-6-2015 [id] => 128019 ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `custom_sort_dt` function to look at the sub keys:

```
function custom_sort_dt($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
}
```

Comment: oh this is nice! Two questions: 1. how would I change ASC to DESC? 2. How can I now push the ids into a new array so that finally i can run a loop for posts with those ordered by dates ids?

Comment: 1: `strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date'])`. 2: Just loop through the array? `foreach ($arr as $item) { $newarr[] = $item['id']; }`

Comment: why as $item and then $arr['id'] ? should it not be $item['id'] ?

Comment: excellent! paste this into your answer and I will accept it as it completes the question, thanks a lot       `$finalOrdered = array();
      foreach ($dateOrdered as $item) { 
       $finalOrdered[] = $item['id']; 
      }`

Comment: @rob.m The current answer solves your issue with ordering. The additional foreach loop is not even necessary, as once you have the ordered array, you already have the ID's within that array. If you *really* feel it's necessary, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: you're right but I then need to run the posts like this `post__in="'.$finalOrdered.'"` so I need a string with comma separated list of ids and to have . it, i need to first create an array and the implode it. Unless you have a better solution?

Comment: Or even better @rob.m use [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php): `implode(',', array_column($arr, 'id'))`

Comment: Yeah, `$arr` is just shorthand for the array you want to use. @rob.m