# How to sort datepickers in get_field_objects()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I have more fields as datepickers on the page. I use get_field_objects () to load them on the page template as I need both name and label and value. My code looks like this:

```
<?php

$fields = get_field_objects();

if( $fields )
{

    foreach( $fields as $field_name => $field )
    {
         $format_in = 'd/m/Y'; // the format your value is saved in (set in the field options)
         $format_out = 'd. m. Y'; // the format you want to end up with
         $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format_in, $field['value']);
         $date_now = new DateTime();
         if ($date_now < $date) {
         ?>
         <div class="col-md-6" id="<?php echo $field['name'] . '_text' ?>">
         <p class="mb-2"><?php echo $field['label']; ?>: <?php echo $date->format( $format_out ); ?></p>
         </div>
         <?php        
         }
    }
}
?>
```

I need to sort $ field [‘value’] to have the dates sorted on the page.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php/40462935)

Comment: Ok but where i should put the usort? Before foreach am I rigth?