# usort On String to Date Converted

Tags: php, sorting, date, usort

I'm trying to take a string in the format of *mdY H:i* and sort it in an array. My code for the sort is:

```
    function orderDates($items) {
    //Sort them. Latest one first
    usort($items, function ($a, $b) {
        $a = date('dmY H:i', strtotime($a));
        $b = date('dmY H:i', strtotime($b));

        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return $items;
}
```

I have a test case of:

```
public function test_orderDates() {
    $items = ["09082020 00:00", "12072020 00:00", "14062020 00:00", "17052020 00:00", "21062020 00:00", "24052020 00:00", "26072020 00:00"];

    $rv = $this->cleanupFolder->orderDates($items);

    $this->assertNotNull($rv);
    $this->assertEquals(7, sizeOf($rv));

    $this->assertEquals("09082020 00:00", $rv[0]);
    $this->assertEquals("26072020 00:00", $rv[1]);
    $this->assertEquals("12072020 00:00", $rv[2]);
    $this->assertEquals("21062020 00:00", $rv[3]);
    $this->assertEquals("14062020 00:00", $rv[4]);
    $this->assertEquals("24052020 00:00", $rv[5]);
    $this->assertEquals("17052020 00:00", $rv[6]);
}
```

I expect it to be in that order but it just comes back in the same order. I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Comment: You try to compare string, keep the unix time value and convert it to a string only after.

Comment: I don't have the unix time value. I have a string which is in the format of dmY. That needs to change to a unix time value before I can compare it

Comment: EDIT: @JérémyCasper I get you now. You are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at the string
`$a = date('dmY H:i', strtotime($a));`

`strtotime($a)` is trying to convert a string to a timestamp. Because you have a custom date format, the string `09082020 00:00` will be converted to `false`.

After that, `date('dmY H:i', false)` will return `01011970 00:00`. This why the sorting doesn't work.

I'll suggest using `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

```
    usort($items, function ($a, $b) {
        $a = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY H:i', $a);
        $b = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY H:i', $b);

        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In this part

```php
date('dmY H:i', strtotime($a));
```

you are trying to create `date` with format but you set value with `strtotime()` which returns Unix timestamp (int). So you are probably looking for something like:

```php
\DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY H:i', $a);
```

So it could be something like:

```php
function orderDates($items) {
    //Sort them. Latest one first
    usort($items, function ($a, $b) {
        $a = \DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY H:i', $a);
        $b = \DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY H:i', $b);

        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return $items;
}
```