# how can I combine the results from two separate MYSQL databases?

Tags: php, mysql

how can I combine the results from two separate MYSQL databases? The databases are on separate servers, they contain identical tables but different data.

I would like to get a list of items from both databases at once but sorted by date.

For example

```
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY date");
$result2 = mysqli_query ($conn2, "SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY date");
```

something like that

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result && $results2)) {...}
```

I know this is incorrect but just to visualize what I want to achieve.

If this is not possible, how else can I achieve this result?

Comment: You have to do this in PHP. Fetch both completely, combine arrays as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. But you can do it in PHP. Once you have both results you would have to sort it in code.

```
$query1 = mysqli_query ($conn1, "SELECT * FROM tab");
$query2 = mysqli_query ($conn2, "SELECT * FROM tab");

$rows1 = mysqli_fetch_all($query1);
$rows2 = mysqli_fetch_all($query2);

$allRows = array_merge($rows1, $rows2);
```

Note that `$allRows` will not be sorted. You can sort it using `usort()` as described in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php), adapted to your date format.